# How can I convert this INSERT INTO statement into an UPDATE SET statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I've tried to convert the below INSERT INTO to an UPDATE SET but I'm having some trouble...I'm using SQL Server 2008

```
INSERT INTO tableA
(c_id, status)
SELECT  tableB.c_id, COUNT(*)
FROM    tableB
    LEFT JOIN tableC
        ON tableB.c_id = tableC.c_id
  WHERE tableC.c_id != tableC.c_id_update
GROUP BY tableB.bl_id
```

What I came up with so far...but I'm running into trouble with the assignments of the variables c_id and items after keyword 'SET'.

```
UPDATE tableA SET
c_id = tableB.c_id
,items -- count(*)??
SELECT  tableB.c_id, COUNT(*)
FROM    tableB
    LEFT JOIN tableC
        ON tableB.c_id = tableC.c_id
  WHERE tableC.c_id != tableC.c_id_update
GROUP BY tableB.bl_id
```

Comment: Which RDBMS (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL)? They all have different syntax for complex UPDATE statements.

Comment: What RDBMS? The join syntax differs.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE A
SET
    A.status = X.c
FROM 
tableA A INNER JOIN (
SELECT  tableB.c_id, COUNT(*) as c
FROM    tableB
    LEFT JOIN tableC
        ON tableB.c_id = tableC.c_id
  WHERE tableC.c_id != tableC.c_id_update
GROUP BY tableB.bl_id ) X
ON A.c_id = X.c_id
```

Comment: It's giving me an error saying "Invalid column name c_id". I presume that you meant A.c_id not A.id?

Comment: No, still not working. Giving me same error "Invalid column name c_id". Did you also mean to say "SELECT c_id FROM table A...." on the 4th line?

Comment: no , if the select is good , it should work like this  does the select works ? after INNER JOIN

Comment: does this select give you any result ?  SELECT * FROM tableA A INNER JOIN (
SELECT  tableB.c_id, COUNT(*) as c
FROM    tableB
    LEFT JOIN tableC
        ON tableB.c_id = tableC.c_id
  WHERE tableC.c_id != tableC.c_id_update
GROUP BY tableB.bl_id ) X
ON A.c_id = X.c_id

Comment: i wrote "update item" , but you have (c_id, status)
try now , i updated the query

Comment: Well, the SELECT query that you posted above works. However, when I try the original one it still gives me the same error. It's complaining that c_id in X.c_id is invalid column name

Comment: ok great it works now! I forgot to add the c_id in the select statement. However, how can I make the count( * ) input the number 0 rather than an empty space in the tableA? Currently it places a empty string value if the count is zero...How can I make it insert an actual 0

Comment: hmm and another thing...when i run the SELECT query only i get 331 rows selected. but when i run the whole UPDATE query, it only updates 325. any idea as to why the discrepancy?

Comment: you have a condition : tableC.c_id != tableC.c_id_update - you have to see if this gives you the different count

Answer (score 0):

I share my secret to converting any select to an update, embed the select part of the query as a comment:

```
UPDATE A 
    SET     items = X.c 
--select  Aitems, X.c,* 
FROM  tableA A 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT  tableB.c_id, COUNT(*) as c 
            FROM    tableB    
            LEFT JOIN tableC        
                ON tableB.c_id = tableC.c_id   
            WHERE tableC.c_id != tableC.c_id_update 
            GROUP BY tableB.bl_id ) X 
    ON A.id = X.c_id
```

I also try to make sure I show the field I am updating and the field I am using for the new value at the fron tof  the list (if there are a lot of fields in the select). This makes it easy to determine if what you think you are going to update is in fact what you wanted but running the query from the select keyword on.